# docker-compose doesn't build image from latest commit of git repository

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a git repository (the repository has Dockerfile and docker-entrypoint.sh) that I use as a context for building in docker-compose:

```
 build:
      context: git@git.example.com/example/example-backend.git
```

When I run either one of the following:

```
 1. docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
 2. docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d
 3. docker-compose up -d --build
```

The image is being built from the repository but the files are not up to date with origin/master. They are the one from previous commit.

I checked to see if pulling from git actually works. Doing

```
 git clone git@git.example.com/example/example-backend.git
```

pulls from latest commit.

What am I doing wrong? Docker doesn't work pull it from latest commit in git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have stumbled upon a known missing feature or bug (depending who you ask). You can find out more [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/980). A way to go around this is to use an http(s) url instead of the ssh git one, you try.